# "Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache" - greenDAO, Android

Tags: android, greendao

I am using **GreenDAO** to generate my **DAO** classes, but i am always having the same error on console that i cant figure out what is the problem.

I generate my **DAO** classes, and then i do in my activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this.getApplicationContext(), "OneTableDB.sqlite",
                null);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    }
```

This is all i have on my activity.

My layout is pretty simple too:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

On my console i have an error, that even it doesnt mess with the functional part of the application, i always have it dont know why.

**Console**:

```
OpenGLRenderer - Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
OpenGLRenderer - MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192 
OpenGLRenderer - Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints() 
OpenGLRenderer - MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Do you still work on this problem? If so: What does your schema look like? How do you set your data? How do you access it?